# StopPropogation() not short circuiting in ON_DISPATCH event

Tags: php, zend-framework2

```
<?php


namespace Inventionary;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);



        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'OnDispatch']);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, [$this, 'OnRender']);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }


    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        xdebug_var_dump("Route Dispatch");

        xdebug_var_dump($e->getRouteMatch());
        $e->stopPropagation(true);

        xdebug_var_dump($e->propagationIsStopped());
       //return new \Zend\Http\Response();

    }

    public function onRender(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        xdebug_var_dump("Before Render");
        xdebug_var_dump($e->getRequest()->getMetadata());
        xdebug_var_dump($e->getRouteMatch());

    }
}
```

I was expecting to never see

> "Before Render"

But it is showing it.

If I return Response object from onDispatch() it is working as expected. Please explain in details why stopPropogation() is not preventing triggering onRender() callback. How it is possible to make it work without returning `Response` object. I am bit unclear how its working internally.

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation()` stops further processing of listeners attached to said event, not all remaining events entirely.

Comment: Can you tell what is the difference between returning `Response` object and using setPropogation() and returning false from callback of attatch(). They all suppose to short circuit